# Firebase, .addSnapshotListener on all the nodes

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using FireStore for my Spring-boot project and i made this code work fine. With that i can 
get real time updates on what values are changing inside the collection "values".

```
Firestore firestore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
    CollectionReference valuesCollectionRef = firestore.collection("Users").document("user_name").collection("sensors")
            .document("sensorX").collection("Values");

valuesCollectionRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshot, FirestoreException error) {
            System.out.println(snapshot.getDocumentChanges()
            .get(0).getDocument().get("value"));
        }

    });
```

What I want is a listener on the "Users" collection **which gets triggered when a child is added anywhere in the database**, in "sensorX" or "sensorY" and in different documents of "Users" collection.

Is that possible with Firestore in Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listeners in Firestore are shallow. They listen on a single collection, or (when using a collection group query) on multiple collections with the same name (which presumably have the same data structure). It is not possible to have a listener for a collection and all its subcollections.

But if you want to know whenever anyone's `sensors` collection is modified, a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) **is** what you want.

This example (slightly modified from the documentation) listens for any writes to the `sensors` collection of any user (or any collection named `sensors` elsewhere in the database):

```
db.collectionGroup("sensors").get()
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
          // ...
      }
  });
```

If you'd like to listen to any values of any sensors of any users, you could equally use:

```
db.collectionGroup("Values").get()
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
          // ...
      }
  });
```

The thing to be most away of with that last one is that `Values` is a fairly generic name for a collection, and this will listen to any `Values` collection no matter where it exists in the database. When you're using collection group queries, you'll typically want to use fairly distinctive collection names, such as for example `SensorValues`.